# Webpage link ends in a slash - how can i remove that?

Tags: html, filepath

I'm currently hosting my files on a local server while i build my site. I have my files organised in a way such as this:

```
images
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
about
    index.html
```

I want the index.html file to be `mywebsite.com/about`, but when I click the link to it, it goes to `mywebsite.com/about/`, with a slash on the end like so. How can I get rid of the last slash? Am i organising my files incorrectly?

Comment: The slash indicates that file is the root file of a directory. If you don't want the slash you need to make `/about` a file in your root website directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way it is supposed to work. You are referencing the directory, not a file. When you enter http://mywebsite.com/about, the web server looks for a file called "about" in the root. If it doesn't find it, it looks for a folder called "about." If it finds one, the URL will always end in a slash.

If you really want to have the url end without a slash, you'll need to do one of the following things:

1. Create a file called "about" in the root directory (that your web server knows to handle with the correct handler and mimetype)
2. Use an .htaccess file to rewrite the url, something like:

   `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: I tried the first method, with my .php file, but this simply takes me to the directory.

Comment: That's probably because the file still ends in .php. For the server to find it, it needs to be named "about" without a file extension. The probably you'll have though is that the server will not process it as a PHP file unless you specifically configure it to treat all files without extensions as php files. So it's probably better to create an .htaccess file in the root and add that RewriteRule to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your .htacces file:

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work. In my public_html directory I made a file called .htaccess and inserted the code above. Is this correct?

Comment: Try to put the .htaccess file in the sub directory, in your case the about folder.